# Processing command-line-args-left?

Tags: elisp

I have a function in which I pass a filename followed by several integer parameters.  The problem is that I now want to run my code as a Unix script, using [command-line-args-left](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html) to pass parameters from the command line.  When **#1** calls process-args, a list is created with all of the values.  In **#2**, a list of a list {eg. ((1 2 3)) } is created upon entry to process-args.  What is the best way to keep my code generic so I can handle both cases **#1** and **#2** in the same function?

```
(defun process-args (filename &rest cols) ...) 
(process-args filename 1 2 3); #1
(process-args (car command-line-args-left) (cdr command-line-args-left)); #2
```

Here is some working sample code with which I'm testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

(defun process-args (filename &rest cols)
           (princ (concat "Script Name: " file "\n"))
       (princ (concat "File parameter: " filename "\n"))
       (princ "Other arg values: ")
       (princ cols)
       (princ "\nIs list: ")
       (princ (listp cols))
       (princ "\n----------\n")
       (while cols
         (princ (car cols))
         (princ "...")
         (setq cols (cdr cols)))
       (princ "\n"))

(print "===== Version #1: Base case - becomes (1 2 3) =====")
(process-args (car command-line-args-left) 1 2 3)

(print "===== Version #2: Passing cdr of list as one string =====")
(process-args (car command-line-args-left) (mapconcat 'identity (cdr command-line-args-left) " "));

(print "===== Version #3: Test of list of list - becomes ((1 2 3)) =====")
(process-args (car command-line-args-left) '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [`'apply`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Calling-Functions) to flatten out the last argument (the last argument to `'apply' is a list of arguments, use`'funcall` if you don't have the last bit in a list).

So, version #3 above would be handled so:

```
(apply 'process-args (car command-line-args-left) '(1 2 3))
```

(The other invocations wouldn't change.)